# Obtaining current user id from outside of controller

Tags: asp.net

I am currently implementing a Background Service in a web application, in which this services got an implementation of a method which do requires to get current logged in user id.

i am trying to get access to the current logged in user, but making this call obviously from outside of a controller cause an error with this following
Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
 public class ScopedProcessingService: IScopedProcessingService
{
    private readonly ILogger<ScopedProcessingService> logger;
    private readonly IEweUserManager eweUserManager;
    private IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    public ScopedProcessingService(IEweUserManager eweUserManager,
        ILogger<ScopedProcessingService> logger, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.eweUserManager = eweUserManager;
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), stoppingToken);
      var userId = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
  /* i am getting the error in this line */
                

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
                {
                    var result = await eweUserManager.FindAsync(userId);
                    if (result.IsSuccess)
                    {
                       .. the rest of the code
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're doing a background service, there is no HttpContext, so it's in appropriate to use a IHttpContextAccessor. What exactly are you doing with this service? What are you trying to accomplish, and what's supposed to initiate this process?

Comment: the initiate purpose of this background service is to pass  current user id  each 10 seconds while user is logged in via utilizing WCF method which will then will implement other methods

Comment: is there anyway that can assist me to obtain the current logged in user id within this background service ?

Comment: That would probably be something you would have to start from within an HttpContext. From there, you can call the WCF service, or perhaps add a record to some queue, and then have a background service pick up the user's ID from the queue and send it along to the WCF service. But let's back up even further: what actually is the purpose of this? Are you just trying to track when a user is on your site? If I were a non-technical person, how would you describe the purpose of what you're trying to do?

Comment: is there a way to start the service like for example from within the Home Controller, which will assist me to call the service to start as well i can pass the user id

Comment: You have not addressed my previous comment. Please read it again and address the questions I raised.